# Add to a spirit qi symbol table in a semantic action

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

Going by the opening paragraph of the [boost::spirit::qi::symbols documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/string/symbols.html), I assumed that it wouldn't be too hard to add symbols to a qi::symbols from a semantic action. Unfortunately it appears to be not as straightforward as I would have assumed.

The following bit of test code exhibits the problem:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

typedef qi::symbols<char, unsigned int> constants_dictionary;

template <typename Iter> struct parser : public qi::grammar<Iter, qi::space_type> {

    parser(constants_dictionary &dict) : parser::base_type(start) {

        start = qi::lit("@") >> ((+qi::char_) >> qi::uint_)[dict.add(qi::_1, qi::_2)];
    }

    qi::rule<Iter> start;
};

int main() {
    constants_dictionary dict;
    parser<std::string::const_iterator> prsr(dict);
    std::string test = "@foo 3";
    parse(test.begin(), test.end(), prsr, qi::space);
}
```

Gives type errors related to qi::_2 from VS2010:

```
C:\Users\k\Coding\dashCompiler\spirit_test.cpp(12) : error C2664: 'const boost::
spirit::qi::symbols<Char,T>::adder &boost::spirit::qi::symbols<Char,T>::adder::o
perator ()<boost::spirit::_1_type>(const Str &,const T &) const' : cannot conver
t parameter 2 from 'const boost::spirit::_2_type' to 'const unsigned int &'
        with
        [
            Char=char,
            T=unsigned int,
            Str=boost::spirit::_1_type
        ]
        Reason: cannot convert from 'const boost::spirit::_2_type' to 'const uns
igned int'
        No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conv
ersion, or the operator cannot be called
        C:\Users\k\Coding\dashCompiler\spirit_test.cpp(10) : while compiling cla
ss template member function 'parser<Iter>::parser(constants_dictionary &)'
        with
        [
            Iter=std::_String_const_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::al
locator<char>>
        ]
        C:\Users\k\Coding\dashCompiler\spirit_test.cpp(21) : see reference to cl
ass template instantiation 'parser<Iter>' being compiled
        with
        [
            Iter=std::_String_const_iterator<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::al
locator<char>>
        ]
```

(Apologies for the nasty VS2010 error-style)

What syntax am I supposed to be using to add (and later on, remove) symbols from this table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question [has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8780604/how-to-add-qisymbols-in-grammariterator-double). However, there is quite a range of problems with your posted code, so I'll fix them up one by one to spare you unnecessary staring at pages of error messages.

The working code (plus verification of output) is **[here on liveworkspace.org](http://liveworkspace.org/code/c31791ff93d0fa3d899e499599126f40)**.

Notes:

1. the semantic action must be a Phoenix *actor*, i.e. you need

   - `boost::bind`, `phoenix::bind`, `std::bind`
   - `phoenix::lambda<>` or `phoenix::function<>`
   - a function pointer or polymorphic calleable object (as per the documentation)

     I'd recommend `phoenix::bind` (in this particular case), which I show below
2. There was a mismatch between the parser's skipper and the start rule
3. `qi::char_` eats *all characters*. Combined with the skipper, this resulted
    in parse failure, because (obviously) the digits in the value were also being
    eaten by `+qi::char_`. I show you one of many solutions, based on `qi::lexeme[+qi::graph]`
4. use `qi::lexeme` to 'bypass' the skipper (i.e. to prevent +qi::graph to cut
   across whitespace because the skipper, well, skipped it)
5. `qi::parse` doesn't take a skipper; use `qi::phrase_parse` for that (the
   reason it *appeared* to work is that any trailing 'variadic' arguments are
   bound to the exposed attributes of the parser, which in this case are
   unspecified, and therefore `qi::unused_type`).
6. if you want to pass `test.begin()` and `test.end()` directly to
   `qi::phrase_parse`, you need to make it clear that you want const iterators. The
   more typical solution would be to introduce explicitely typed variables
   (`first` and `last`, e.g.)

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_USE_PHOENIX_V3
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <string>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace phx = boost::phoenix;

typedef qi::symbols<char, unsigned int> constants_dictionary;

template <typename Iter> struct parser : qi::grammar<Iter, qi::space_type> 
{
    parser(constants_dictionary &dict) : parser::base_type(start) 
    {
        start = qi::lit("@") >> (qi::lexeme [+qi::graph] >> qi::uint_)
            [ phx::bind(dict.add, qi::_1, qi::_2) ]
            ;
    }

    qi::rule<Iter, qi::space_type> start;
};

int main() {
    constants_dictionary dict;
    parser<std::string::const_iterator> prsr(dict);
    const std::string test = "@foo 3";

    if (qi::phrase_parse(test.begin(), test.end(), prsr, qi::space))
    {
        std::cout << "check: " << dict.at("foo") << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I could have sworn I had seen it before, but neither google nor the onsite search were helping me. And I was a bit over-aggressive in chopping out from the real parser (which explains pretty much all of the "other problems"), sorry. Thanks for setting the record straight on them as well though.